# How to get onClick function with false animate queues to also run an outside function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/xgJns/184/

Hi! I am wondering how to get the "resize" function to run when the onClick code is clicked, in a **specific part** of the code that I've marked with the comment "Here". My attempt was:

```
$('#Div5').animate({
    marginLeft: isOut ? '120px' : '0px'
}, { duration: 200, queue: false }, resize);
```

but for some reason that isn't working. I'm not sure if my website in particular is just messed up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated click function, add third parameter `function(){}` to `animate` and call `resize()` wrapped in it:

```
 $('#Div1').click(function() {
    if ( $('#Div2').is(":visible") ) {
        $('#Div2').hide(0);
    }

    $('#Div5').toggleClass('isSize');
    var isSize = $('#Div5').hasClass('isSize');
    $('#Div5').animate({
        width: isSize ? '408' : '204px'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false }, function(){
        resize();
    });

    $('#Div5').toggleClass('isOut');
    var isOut = $('#Div5').hasClass('isOut');
    $('#Div5').animate({
        marginLeft: isOut ? '120px' : '0px'
    }, { duration: 200, queue: false }, function(){
        resize();
    });     

    $('#Div3').fadeToggle(500);
    $('#Div4').fadeToggle(500);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xgJns/186/)